# Amazon RDS: encryption on port 3306?

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

It looks like Amazon's RDS instances have encryption turned off for their connections - is there a way to turn on SSL encryption on RDS instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only supported for mysql RDS instances.  See the last two questions in the faq section "security"

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#How_do_I_secure_Amazon_RDS_DB_Instances_running_within_my_VPC